# The package is accessible from more than one module problem under VSCode only

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-module

I have a project which builds fine under `gradle` as well as in the `IntelliJ` IDE run configuration.

But it gives a problem in the `VSCode` IDE:

```
The package javax.crypto is accessible from more than one module
```

The are no `module-info.java` file in the entire project.

The modules listed are:

```
~/Desktop/dev/projects/pid2 % java --list-modules                                                                                                                                                                                                          
java.*
jdk.*
```

The `VSCode` home setting for the JDK is:

```
"java.home": "/Users/stephane.eybert/.sdkman/candidates/java/current",
```

and it is the version:

```
~/Desktop/dev/projects/pid2 % /Users/stephane.eybert/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java -version                                                                                                                                                      (master)pid2
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

I tried with changing the JDK so as to use the same one as `IntelliJ` is using, but the problem remained the same.

The `IntelliJ` JDK version is:

```
~/Desktop % /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+10-b304.77)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+10-b304.77, mixed mode)
```

The VSCode version is:

```
Version: 1.40.0
Commit: 86405ea23e3937316009fc27c9361deee66ffbf5
Date: 2019-11-06T17:09:34.601Z
Electron: 6.1.2
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.0.0
```

Comment: have you add it to the `.classpath`

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. You suggest I add what ?

Comment: Is there a setting to disable the checking of conflicts between the noname module containing the packages of the CLASSPATH and the packages in the modules of the MODULEPATH ?

Comment: I'm sorry for replying to you so late. Is there any progress?Have you tried to unistall and reinstall your jdk ?

Comment: Yes I upgraded to the JDK java version `"11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS` but the issue remained exactly the same.

Comment: Please can you upload a simplified facsimile of your project that has the same issue? There is obviously something going on that is impossible to diagnose with the limited snippets of info you've shared so far.

Comment: @deduper Yes I was thinking the same, but it's a company project, and I cannot share its source code. The only thing I could do is try to create a project from scratch with a similar generic structure, and see if I can replicate the issue in it.

Comment: Yes. Please? Thanks. Incidentally, „*simplified facsimile*“ is the short way of saying: «*try to create a project from scratch with a similar generic structure, and see if I can replicate the issue in it*» :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am experiencing the same exact issue.

Comment: I had left the company and forgot about that issue. I have no longer access to the project.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue is on `java.util` package.

In each java project there will be `.settings` folder created by vscode, in that folder open `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file, change the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance` option from `11` to `1.8` and clean workspace

or

Changing the maven-compiler-plugin source and target to 1.8 worked for me.

Both the ways worked for me.